# How can I do like SUMIFS in excel, but adding based on one criteria, subtracting based on another

Tags: excel

I have two tables in Excel, call one the Transfer table, and one the Location table.

The locations have a series of codes (e.g. A1, A2, A3, A4).

In the transfer table, I choose an Origin Code, and a Destination Code, and enter an amount.

I want the Location table to update so that if the Code is in the Origin, it gets a negative change in amount, and if it is in the Destination it gets a positive change.

Quick example: Origin A1, Destination A2, Amount 5000 (Transfer Table)
A1 Change = -5000
A2 Change = 5000

But I want to do this in a single formula.  I've been trying to play around with SUMIFS and SUMPRODUCT but so far I'm not quite sure how to accomplish this.

Comment: while you have made an effort to describe what is going on in words, it would be helpful to see a snipet of what your are trying to do in an example table.  So of those sumproducts and sum ifs formulas that you have tried, what do they look like?  Post them in your question and we can point out where things did not go right potentially.

Answer (score 1):

If I read this correctly, you want to calculate a running total based on values coming in and going out of specific locations. Consider the following screenshot:

[image]

The locations are listed in a table on the left. In order to calculate anything, you may want to use a column for starting balance. Then you can add values that are received by that destination and subtract values that originate in that location with a formula that uses Sumif() as demonstrated. The formula starts in C2 and has been copied down.

```
=B2+SUMIF(G:G,A2,H:H)-SUMIF(F:F,A2,H:H)
```

- Location A1 started with 100, had 50 going out and 30 coming in, so is now at 80.
- Location A2 started with 100 and had 50 come in, so is now at 150
- Location A4 started at 100 and hat 30 going out, so is now at 70